# UPS XML API: Where is per shipment billing data?

Tags: ups

As another post indicated, UPS developer documentation is a disaster.  I am having a difficult time locating the proper API to pull in billing data based on shipment ID (or tracking number or reference number).  Would it be Quantum View?  I reviewed the documentation and do not see that info in the example XML response.  I see UPS China specifically has a billing API...I'm located in North America.  Any help at all would be grea.

Answer (score 0):

Per UPS tech support this doesn't exist for North America yet.